# Computing the induced homomorphisms of derived functors using acyclic resolutions

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra, kt.k-theory-and-homology

Let's suppose that $F\colon \mathcal A\to \mathcal B$ is a right exact additive functor between abelian categories such that $\mathcal A$ has enough projectives.  Standard references shows that if $Q_\bullet\to A\to 0$ is a resolution of $A$ by $F$-acyclic objects, then $L_nF(A)\cong H_n(F(Q_\bullet))$.  Suppose now that $f\colon A\to A'$ is a morphism in $\mathcal A$ and $Q'_\bullet \to A'\to 0$ is a resolution of $A'$ by $F$-acyclic objects.  Suppose moreover, I have a chain map $Q_\bullet\to Q'_\bullet$ over $f$.  Then I get induced homomorphism $f_n\colon H_n(F(Q_\bullet))\to H_n(F(Q'_\bullet))$ which agree with $f$ at the level of $H_0$ (after the natural identifications).  My question is can we choose isomorphisms $L_nF(A)\to H_n(F(Q_\bullet))$ and $L_nF(A')\to H_n(F(Q'_\bullet))$ so that these isomorphisms intertwine $f_n$ and $L_nF(f)$ for all $n$?

Any pointers to references would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to apply $F$ to your resolutions before taking homology.

Comment: @user509184, Sorry I will fix

Comment: Here is how I faintly recall this working, but I haven't tried to write anything down to be careful about it, so caveat emptor! If your resolutions $Q$ and $Q'$ were projective resolutions, then it's standard that the map induced by $f$ in $L_*F$ is the one induced by $H_*(f)$ from $A$ to $A'$. So you just need to compare $Q$ and $Q'$ to projective resolutions. I think the standard approach is to take Cartan-Eilenberg resolutions of $Q$ and $Q'$, and use projectivity of the CE resolutions to give you a map between them which is induced by $f$ and yet also induces the right map in $L_*F$.

Comment: @user509184 I was trying something along that line but my problem was to check that that the map from the projective resolution to Q is a quasi-isomorphism. The proof I’m used to that F-acyclic resolutions work is usually based on dimension shifts.

Comment: I think that's a very special case of Theorem XVII.4.3 in the original Cartan-Eilenberg homological algebra book.

Comment: @user509184,  I’ll try to sort out what they are saying and if it fits my context. Thanks.

Comment: I think that it suffices to assume that $\mathcal A$ has enough $F$-acyclic objects (e.g. sheaf categories usually do not have enough projectives).